Return multi-line ssh output to separate variables?
RHEL 8.10
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1k  FIPS 25 Mar 2021
As expected, this line (with two embedded commands) returns two rows:
$ ssh -q remoteserver "ls -1 /proc/${p}/fd | wc -l ; ps -Ostate  -p${p} | tail -n1"
969
1353432 S S ?        00:00:12 pgpool: wait for accept lock

How do I store each line in a separate variable on the local server?  (Because I have to run ssh hundreds of times, and each one takes more than 0.25 seconds, I'm trying to minimize the number of times that I call ssh.)
The goal is to have, for example, variable FDcnt have the value 969, and PidState be 1353432 S S ?        00:00:12 pgpool: wait for accept lock.
This works, but seems a bit too hackish:
blarge=()
while read -r
do 
    blarge+=("$REPLY")
done <<<$(ssh -q FISPCDSPGS202c "ls -1 /proc/${p}/fd | wc -l ; ps -Ostate  -p${p} | tail -n1")
echo ${blarge[0]}
970
$ echo ${blarge[1]}
1353432 S S ? 00:00:12 pgpool: fis_cds cdsbmop 10.55.96.151(33710) idle


"Because I have to run ssh hundreds of times, and each one takes more than 0.25 seconds" – If you don't use connection sharing then you should start. Do you use it?

@KamilMaciorowski no, I don't.  Will look into it.

Run ssh -M -S /tmp/mysocket -f -N remoteserver to start a master connection in the background. Then time ssh -S /tmp/mysocket remoteserver "your command here". How fast is it now? Repeat with different commands. Finally ssh -S /tmp/mysocket -O exit remoteserver to terminate the master connection.

@KamilMaciorowski this is a script which runs from cron. The master connection needs to stay open when using connection sharing, though.

A script can very well run ssh -fNMS … first, ssh -S … -O exit … last and many ssh -S … in between. The only "problem" is to use different sockets if two or more instances may work in parallel. For now test this without a script, only to know how much faster (if ever) your ssh commands can be.

set +m; shopt -s lastpipe; ssh ... | { read a; read b; }; echo "$a $b"

@KamilMaciorowski already tried it interactively.  Much faster!  Will now try from cron; if it works, I'll ask you to write that up as an Answer.

My general approach is to capture the multi-line output into a variable, then use one or two more commands to extract the individual parts of that output into separate variables.  I only have to run the complex command once, and I have more power available in my script to capture the desired parts into their own variables.  (the "more power" is using bash variable expansions and/or external commands, instead of trying to pack everything into a single, very complex pipeline)

@SottoVoce how does that work when on of the lines has a variable number of words in it?

@KamilMaciorowski make that an answer, and I'll accept it.

Well, it's a good solution, but not a good answer to the question entitled "Return multi-line ssh output to separate variables?" See XY problem. It's good you told us what your X was. Connection sharing solves X. Still the question is explicitly about your Y and there is already one answer that solves Y, not X. If not the answer, then we could rebuild your question and concentrate more on X. With the answer the thread is about Y. Period. Connection sharing does not address Y at all. I don't like it when answers solve different problems, I will pass.

@RonJohn one way is var=$(cmd-has-multiple-output-lines) and another is the while read loop you have in your script.  But a full discussion of this approach (and how useful it is for ssh commands) is too much for comments.  It would need to be a separate question.

@KamilMaciorowski this works for me: readonly Socket=/tmp/mysocket-$$ then ssh -M -S $Socket -f -N $Server and ssh -S $Socket -O exit $Server.

One method could be to assign the values to an array such as in bash:
IFS=$'\n' blarge=($( ssh… ))
printf "> %s <\n" "${blarge[@]}"

But the problem with this is that the lines from ssh are subject to globbing.
Fixing up your own code, which already avoids the globbing problem, is probably better:
blarge=()
while IFS= read -r
do 
    blarge+=("$REPLY")
done < <(ssh -q FISPCDSPGS202c "ls -1 '/proc/$p/fd' | wc -l ; ps -Ostate  -p'$p' | tail -n1")
printf "> %s <\n" "${blarge[@]}"


Did you "just" remove a <, add a   and remove a $, or did I miss something?

@RonJohn IFS= on the read -r, and I swapped <<<$(…) for < <(…); and in the ssh command I (have now) quoted the $p variable. The first and third are good coding the second is personal preference

Or mapfile -t blarge < <(ssh ...) (or the synonym readarray). Or as Cyrus hinted, with jobcontrol off and lastpipe on ssh ... | mapfile -t blarge

@dave_thompson_085 I always seem to forget about the array reader mapfile
